# Why is my image not storing in a specified folder in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, file-handling, laravel-5.6

In my form, I asked for an image to upload. Then I already validated it and it works. But the file is not stored in the uploads folder.

Here's a snippet of my ProductController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Validate fields
    $this->validate($request, [
        'product_name' => 'required',
        'product_price' => 'required',
        'product_desc' => 'required',
        'product_img' => 'image|required'
    ]);

    // Upload image
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        app()->make('path.public/uploads');
        $image = $request->image;

        $image->move('uploads', $image->getClientOriginalName());


    }

    /*// Save the data into database
    Product::create([
        'name' => $request->product_name,
        'price' => $request->product_price,
        'description' => $request->product_desc,
        'image' => $request->image->getClientOriginalName()
    ]);


    // Echo a session message
    $request->session()->flash('msg', 'Your product has been added');


    // Redirect to view page
    return redirect('/products');*/

}
```

I already tried looking at other possible solutions but the other questions were already at storing the image in the database. I also tried checking if `uploads` was a directory and existed, and it is.

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-uploads): This is how it should look in your controller:

`if($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $request->file('image')->store('uplodads/', 'public');
}`

This would store the image in `/storage/app/public/uploads` by default. You can also change the `public` path in `/config/filesystems.php`. You can then access the file (if you linked the storage) with `asset('storage/uploads'.$img_name)`.

Comment: I didn't change yet the `public` path, because I wanted only function store() to use the uploads folder. Regarding the code, I have tried it and change my controller, but the image won't still save.

Comment: Did the `uploads` folder appeared in `storage/app/public`? Also the app has enabled debugging and doesn't throw any error? Also make sure you using `Illuminate\Http\Request;` not the `Request` facade.

Comment: Thank you, the second parameter (`store('uplodads/', 'public')`) fixed my issue as it now stores under `storage/public` folder. On Laravel 7

Answer (score 0):

```
app()->make('path.public/uploads');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved it. The variable was wrong all along. Instead of it being `product_img`, I placed `image`.

Here's the updated code:

```
    // Validate fields
    $this->validate($request, [
        'product_name' => 'required',
        'product_price' => 'required',
        'product_desc' => 'required',
        'product_img' => 'image|required'
    ]);

    // Upload image
    if($request->hasFile('product_img')) {
        $image = $request->product_img;         
        $image->move('uploads', $image->getClientOriginalName());   
    }
```